# Smoothest Way To Implement Back to Back UIAnimations

Tags: ios, objective-c, uianimation

I need to have my character jump (increase the `origin.y` by `50` and reverse) in a game I am creating.

So far I have come across two ways of doing this:

**Method 1:**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect frame = self.kevinImageView.frame;
                     frame.origin.y -= 50;
                     self.kevinImageView.frame = frame;
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     CGRect frame = self.kevinImageView.frame;
                     frame.origin.y = 135;
                     self.kevinImageView.frame = frame;
                 }];
```

**Issues:** At the end of every complete jump animation (up and down) the `ImageView` jumps up and then back down (due probably to the tiny amount it takes for the `completion` block to be called). This is noticeable and I would much rather do without it.

**Method 2:**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect frame = self.kevinImageView.frame;
                     frame.origin.y -= 50;
                     self.kevinImageView.frame = frame;
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                      animations:^{
                                          CGRect frame = self.kevinImageView.frame;
                                          frame.origin.y += 50;
                                          self.kevinImageView.frame = frame;
                                      }];
                 }];
```

**Issues:** If I tap the view (I use a `UITapGuestureRecognizer`) and the `ImageView` is in the completion animation (going back down), the `Image View` will snap back to the bottom instead of finishing its animation. Again not a major issue, but something which I should be able to avoid.

Is there any method I have not come across which will resolve both of these issues, or a way to fix one of the methods?

Comment: >> In your Method 2 you miss the completion block. Did you add it?

Comment: @Rashad In the second animation?

Comment: In your second animation you missed completion block (In method 2).

Comment: The `completion` block is not required. I did not think I needed one until now (see answer).

Comment: @cabellicar123 I have another solution, have a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you *disable* your `UITapGuestureRecognizer` when the animation is still running? And then *enable* it when the animation finishes.

```
if (!self.isAnimationRunning) {
        self.isAnimationRunning = YES;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
             animations:^{
                 CGRect frame = self.kevinImageView.frame;
                 frame.origin.y -= 50;
                 self.kevinImageView.frame = frame;
             } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                                  animations:^{
                                      CGRect frame = self.kevinImageView.frame;
                                      frame.origin.y += 50;
                                      self.kevinImageView.frame = frame;
                                  } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         self.isAnimationRunning = NO;   
                   }];
             }];
}
```

Comment: hmm... why is there a down voting with this answer?

Comment: I modified you idea slightly to work with option 2. I just disabled the `UITapGestureRecognizer` before any of the animations and reenabled it in the second `completion` block.

Comment: I also do not know why this answer was down voted. It would be helpful if that person explained their reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very interested in this question so I do a simple demo to do a back to back animation.

I think maybe you can just use `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse` and `UIViewAnimationRepeat` option to achieve a autoreverse animation.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
             delay:0
             options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationRepeat
             animations:^{
                 [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
                 self.kevinImageView.center = CGPointMake(self.kevinImageView.center.x ,self.kevinImageView.center.y - 25);
             } completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 self.kevinImageView.center = CGPointMake(self.kevinImageView.center.x ,self.kevinImageView.center.y + 25);
             }];
```

and you can also set `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` if you want to enable use interaction during the animation.